# facebook canvas app inside iframe redirects and signed request

Tags: facebook, iframe, redirect, canvas

I am building a facebook canvas app and i am using the signed request parameter provided by facebook to check if the user has already authenticated the app. (by checking the presence of user_id field). If the user_id is not set then I redirect the user to a uthorization page (using top.location in javascript).

The problem is that, in my application I need to make internal redirects and then i can´t get signed request anymore.

Possible solutions:
1). Change the way i check if the user has installed the app . Get the current user (not sure if I need signed request anyway). Then use the graph api to check the permissions).

2). allways use client side redirects. (then I can allways get the signed request and it is also provides better navigation to the user because the top url change.) Not sure about the performance compared with iframe redirects.

What is the best option, in your opintion.

PS: I am using PHP SDK / symfony framework and the javascript sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way to handle this is to set a cookie to carry forward either signed_request or whatever subset of data from it you need, so it is available on all pages.  You can do this directly or by using PHP sessions to store the data.

However I am personally of the opinion that cookies are a bad idea within iframe apps. For an alternate approach that may do what you need, have a look at http://www.braintilt.com/fbcookies.php .